# how to infer population proportion from samples from 2 disjoint subgroups?

Tags: inference, proportion, sample

Suppose that I know that a large population consists of equal numbers of men and women.  I sample 1000 men and ask whether they have ever eaten an avocado.  Some number M say yes.  Then I sample 1000 women and ask them the same question.  Some number W say yes.

Now, I know how to construct a confidence interval for the proportion of men who have eaten an avocado, or the proportion of women who have done the same:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

But given this data, how can I construct a confidence interval for the proportion of people in the **total population** who have eaten one?

In theory I could pretend that I had asked a random sample of 2000 people in the general population, and that (M + W) had said yes, and I could use the resulting Wilson score interval (for example).  But my sample of 1000 men and 1000 men should be a better approximation of the population than a random sample of 2000 would be, so presumably the actual confidence interval should be a bit tighter in this case.